Выходит ошибка executor. Как исправить эту ошибку?
import config
from aiogram import Bot, types, executor, Dispatcher

bot = Bot(token=config.token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echobot(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)

Выходит ошибка:
File "c:\Users\Админ\Downloads\Telegram_chat\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, types, executor, Dispatcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'


дубликаты где-то здесь

Скорее всего у вас установлена версия Aiogram 3.x, объекта executor с данной версии не существует.
